# How to set the subject of the email to have a combination of static words and fields name?

Tags: workflow

Currently, I have two fields called 'User Full Name' and 'Country Name'. I need the subject of the email to have the following format:

A New feedback from {User Full Name} of {Country Name}

However, it was noted that the SharePoint 2007 workflow 'Send an email' only allow either of the following parameter - meaning either static words (like 'A New feedback from') or a single field name (e.g. {User Full Name})

So, Is there a way to customize the subject of the email?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a build dynamic string option to your workflow and have it construct the subject as you'd like it.  Use that variable as the subject line for the email.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear cut answer. By the way, I have edit your answer to include two pictures that I think it will be very helpful for those who are looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit this workflow in sharepoint designer which would allow you to do this.

Comment: sorry, are you referring to SP 2010?

Comment: in both, u can use sp designer for 2010 and for 2007 use designer 2007 but i'm not sure about 2007 i've done it in sp 2010

Comment: please make your answer more useful by adding examples

Comment: yes sure unfortunately i do not have links as i did it on my own but surely remember to do it next time. Thank you